# Set degree of parallelism for a single operation in Python

Tags: python, apache-flink

I execute my program with a dop > 1 but I do not want multiple output files. In Java `myDataSet.writeAsText(outputFilePath, WriteMode.OVERWRITE).setParallelism(1);`is working as expected.

But when I try the same in Python it does not work. This is my code:  `myDataSet.write_text(output_file, write_mode=WriteMode.OVERWRITE).set_degree_of_parallelism(1)`

Is there a possibilty to achieve this behaviour in Python?

Comment: Sound like a bug in the Python API. Maybe you should ask at the user- or dev-mailing list. If the Bug gets confirmed, you could open an JIRA for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug but an unsupported feature. It is currently not possible to set the parallelism for a single operator, but only the complete job.

I have opened a JIRA for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3275

Answer (score 1):

For users who are unaware, Apache Flink added this feature couple of months back.

Here is the short doc from Flink :-

> The default parallelism can be overwriten for an entire job by calling setParallelism(int parallelism) on the ExecutionEnvironment or by passing -p  to the Flink Command-line frontend. It can be overwritten for single transformations by calling setParallelism(int parallelism) on an operator.